# Can my vps_ip be set as a proxy to let wget use with?

Tags: shell, proxy, wget

There is a $url which is blocked by gfw.
Now i want to download the content from the $url this way.

```
ssh  root@vps_ip  #to use my vps_ip to break the gfw.      
wget -c  $url  -O /home/material  #to get the content on /home/material in my remote vps disk.      
scp root@vps_ip:/home/material    /home  #to get the /home/material in my remote vps disk into my local disk .
```

Can my vps_ip be set as a proxy to let wget use with?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.baidu.com/search?q=wget+socks+proxy

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38755/how-to-download-a-file-through-an-ssh-server

---

Option 1, with the use of `socksify` from the [`security/dante`](http://ports.su/security/dante) package:

```
sudo pkg_add dante

ssh -N -C -D 1080 root@$vps_ip &

SOCKS_SERVER=localhost:1080 socksify wget -c $url -O /home/material
```

---

Option 2, by piping the download through `stdout` / `stdin`:

```
ssh -C root@$vps_ip "wget -O- $url" >> /home/material
```

Comment: it is `ssh -N -D 1080 root@$vps_ip &`  not ` ssh -N -D 1080 root@vps_ip &`

Comment: SOCKS_SERVER=localhost:1080 socksify wget -c $url -O /home/material
bash: socksify: command not found

Comment: some bugs in option1.

Comment: well, yeah, you have to install `socksify`!  you never mentioned which system you have, so, can't be a fully complete solution

Comment: `socksify` is part of dante; http://ports.su/security/dante , e.g., you'd install it as `pkg_add dante` on OpenBSD

Comment: In my debian8.1:apt-get install -y socksify
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package socksify

Answer (score 1):

If you have you can use at `http://example.com:8080` then you can tell wget to use it with:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://example.com:8080
wget http://different.example.com
```

Comment: wget  www.google.com  -O /home/chrome.html
--2015-09-02 10:29:06--  http://www.google.com/
Resolving www.google.com (www.google.com)... 216.58.221.132, 2404:6800:4005:80b::2004
Connecting to www.google.com (www.google.com)|216.58.221.132|:80...

Comment: The cursor stop there forever.

Comment: will i open the port  8080 on my vps?